SLURM Executor Plugin Error: SLURM Accounting is disabled
I'm trying to run a 5 static node parallel cluster snakemake workflow using the slurm executor plugin provided with snakemake version 8+.
I developed my snakefile and used the following command to run the script:
snakemake --executor slurm --jobs 5 \
  --use-conda --keep-going \
  --latency-wait 60 --notemp \
  --rerun-incomplete --verbose

I ended up getting errors for each job saying the accounting storage is not enabled. Unfortunately, I'm unable to enable it due to budget and time constraints. Is there a work around for this?
Also, when running squeue and sinfo, 1 node is in the MIX state, one is ALLOC, and the other 3 are idle. Any help would be appreciated.
